How to pass data from layout.js to children components in Nextjs?
I was exploring the app router in Next 14 and was wondering if there was any way to pass data from layout.js to its children without making it a client component.
I'm trying to find a way to pass data from layout.js to it's children, but it should be a server component.

why would you want to pass the data from the layout.jsx  to page.jsx??? Why don't you fetch the data from the page.jsx?

@JinseokSeo because I have some config data which will be common for all pages and I don't want to fetch it for each page.

Then I think that the Context is way to go and you can wrap the provider in layout.jsx. In that way you can use the data anywhere in the children compoents by useContext
